# Data structure traversal

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree

Lets say I have package **A** version **1** and package **A** version **2**, Will call them **A1** and **A2** respectively.

If I have a pool of packages: **A1**, **A2**, **B1**, **B2**, **C1**, **C2**, **D1**, **D2**

**A1** depends on **B1**, will represent as `(A1, (B1))`.

Plus **A1** depends on any version of package **C** "**C1** or **C2** satisfy **A1**", will represent as `(A1, (C1, C2))`

combining **A1** deps together, then **A1** data-structure becomes: `(A1, (B1), (C1, C2))`

Also **B1** depends on **D1**:  `(B1, (D1))`

**A1** structure becomes: `(A1, ((B1, (D1))), (C1, C2))`

similarly **A2** structure is `(A2, ((B2, (D2))), (C1, C2))`

My question is: How can I select best candidate of package **A**, where I can select based on a condition (for example, the condition is the package does not conflict with current installed packages).

by combining **A1** and **A2**: `((A1, ((B1, (D1))), (C1, C2)), (A2, ((B2, (D2))), (C1, C2)))`

How can I traverse this data structure

So start with **A1**, if doesn't conflict check **B1**, if doesn't conflict check **D1**, if doesn't conflict check (**C1**, **C2**), and take one only either **C1** or **C2**.
With this I end up selecting `(A1, B1, D1, C1)`.

In case if **A1** or any of its deps did not meet the condition, (for example if **B1** conflicts with installed packages), then drop **A1** entirely and move to check **A2**. then end up with `(A2, B2, D2, C1)`.

**What kind of traversal would that be?**

I have been reading about in-order, pre-order, post-order traversal, and wondering if I need to do something similar here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking traversal on a more generic problem rather than working on this instance, I don't think there exists such a traversal.

1. Note that in-order is only applicable to BINARY trees. Any other kind of tree does not have in-order traversal. If your generic problem has `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, then apparently there wouldn't be a binary tree representation.
2. One property about traversal, is that the tree has all the information inclusively in the itself. When you traverse over a tree you never worry about "external information". In your case, your tree is not complete in information - you need to depend on external information to see if there is a conflict. e.g. B1 is installed - this information is never in the tree.

Comment: Thank you. (I'm new to programming and data-structure in general) For first point, yes I'm looking for a generic solution, since a package can have any number of deps, it is not a binary tree. Regarding second point, I'm thinking to keep track of an array during traversing  and push only the nodes that meet the external information.

Comment: If traversing such data-structure is not possible, what would be a good data-structure to represent  such package-dependencies relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adjacency list to represent the data:
Suppose the packages are A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2. 
And A1 depends on B1 and C2, A2 depends on B1 and C1 and C2. 
The above data can be represented as

```
[A1] -> [B1, C2]
[A2] -> [B1, C1, C2]
```

Use **Topological Sorting** to get the order of dependencies